# Maclaurin series involving integral and finding radius of converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Find Maclaurin's series of given function. What is its radius of convergence?
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^3} dt
$$

My attempt:
$$
\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^3} dt = \int_0^x\frac{1}{1-(-t^3)} dt = \int_0^x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n t^{3n}  dt = \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \int_0^x t^{3n}  dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}
$$

How can I find its radius of convergence? I know what to do when there is $x^n$ or $x^{2n}$ involved, but I am stuck on $x^{3n+1}$.

What also bothers me in my attempt is that I have swapped integral sign with infinite series, which I am only allowed to do when there is uniform convergence(?).

Perhaps I should just differentiate g(x):

$$
g'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^3} \text{ which converges for } |x| < 1\\
$$
and then integrate
$$
\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^3n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}
$$

Comment: As a hint: what would you do if the series had $x^n$ or $x^{2n}$ to determine the radius of convergence?

Comment: Integration doesn't change the radius of convergence.  But you can use ratio test to check for sure.

Comment: @Clayton If I had $x^2n$ I would use Cauchy-Hadamard theorem. If there was $x^n$ then I would just use a ratio test.

Comment: $1$. The map $f(x)\mapsto \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ does not change the radius of convergence and the radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ is obviously $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the power of x is 3n+ 1 is not really a problem.  Basically you find the radius of convergence using the "ratio test":  the sum $\sum a_n$ converges if $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|< 1$.  Here $a_n= (-1)^n\frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}$ so $a_{n+1}= (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{3n+ 4}}{3n+ 4}$ and $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \frac{|x|^{3n+4}}{3n+4}\frac{3n+1}{|x|^{3n+1}}= \frac{3n+4}{3n+1}|x|^3$.

(I presume you know that $\frac{|x|^{3n+4}}{|x|^{3n+1}}= |x|^{3n+4-3n-1}= |x|^3$.)

That will be less than 1 if and only if $|x|^3< \frac{3n+1}{3n+4}$ so if $|x|< \sqrt[3]{\frac{3n+1}{3n+4}}$.

What is the limit of that as n goes to infinity?

Comment: It equals to one.

Comment: That was quick!  Yes, so the radius of convergence is 1.

Comment: I would appreciate if you also told me which of my attempts(with finding Maclaurin's Series) was correct. The first or second one? Or perhaps they are the same.

Comment: You say "What also bothers me in my attempt is that I have swapped integral sign with infinite series, which I am only allowed to do when there is uniform convergence(?)."  A power series always converges uniformly within its radius of convergence so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for an alternating series to converge,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$$
In this case we can say that:
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{3n+1}{3n+4}x^3$$
so notice that as $n\to\infty$ we get:
$$|x^3|<1$$
you can take it from here